# django elastic search index for many for many field

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have successfully integrate elastic search in one of my django project by following this tutorial,

[elastic search with django the easy way](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/elasticsearch-with-django-the-easy-way-909375bc16cb)

i have following model structure,

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    product_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    product_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product_name)

class ProductKeyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="products")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def search_indexing(self):
        obj = ProductKeyWordIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            name=self.name,
            product=self.product.product_name,
            date_created=self.date_created,
            date_updated=self.date_updated,
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

where i have create a `search_indexing` method for a `ProductKeyword` model for elastic search indexing. 
when i try to create a new `ProductKeyword` objects, raise the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product_name'
```

at `search_indexing` method where i am indexing `self.product.product_name`, where 
`self.product` is a `m2m` field, in mention, the same method work perfectly for `foreign field`.

i have tried as following by updating the `search_indexing` method to solve the problem,

```
 def search_indexing(self):
    obj = ProductKeyWordIndex(
        meta={'id': self.id},
        name=self.name,
        product=self.product.product_set.all(),
        date_created=self.date_created,
        date_updated=self.date_updated,
    )
    obj.save()
    return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

but raising the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product_set'
```

Comment: can you share also your index mapping? GET /<indexname>/_mapping

Comment: initially i am saving object from shell.

Comment: ok, try with curl: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<yourindex>/_mapping'

Comment: i am facing problem during the ProductKeyword object creation.Even i don't have any data indexed in Elastic database to GET  using curl.